# Creating fluid containers that end almost in the middle of the screen?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a design that I need to create a front-end version of and I'm struggling to figure out how to code some of the elements presented in the design. Specifically fluid container (fluid, as in container that stretches 100% horizontally) that starts from one end of the screen but ends almost in the middle of the screen. It would be easy if it were to end in the middle of the screen but it is supposed to end where the sidebar begins.

Here's a quick visual representation of what I'm talking about:

[image]

The black borders represent the borders of the website itself (container) and the green and red boxes represent the design elements that start from one end of the screen and end somewhere in the middle (where the sidebar begins, for example).

I'm coding this on bootstrap, if it helps.

Edit// This is supposed be responsive as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manage this with pseudo-elements like so.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container {
  min-height: 100%;
  border:3px solid grey;
 width: 70%;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  
}

main {
  flex: 0 0 70%;
  border-right:1px solid green;

}

aside {
  flex: 0 0 30%;
}


.block {
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
}
main .block {
  margin-top: 100px;
}

main .block:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  right: 0;
  top:0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100vw;
  background: rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
}

aside .block {
  margin-top: 25px;
}

aside .block:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  left: 0;
  top:0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100vw;
  background: rgba(0,255,0,0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <main><div class="block"></div></main>
  <aside><div class="block"></div></aside>
</div>
```

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/wabdom)

Note: How you layout the HTML structure is not specifically relevant here. I used `flexbox` because that's what I'm getting used to right now.

Comment: The idea is nice but the website actually needs to have a fixed width (like standard Bootstrap themes usually do) which gradually decreases step-by-step when resizing your window (basic responsive).

Comment: Ahh I see now. Never really looked into flex that deeply. Thank you for this. This makes things a lot easier.